# How to add html in a location above Razor code ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC4. I am curious, is there a way to conditionally add/change html code that is higher up in the file than where the conditional statement is?

I am using a partial, and I want to add a button at the top of page to hide and unhide a row that contains M. only if this certain condition code exists in the table. I tried using RendorSection but apparently that doesn't work in a partial.

Currently, I hide the button based on the model being empty or null. The model is just a list. But I want to take it further and hide the button conditionally on if the value M exists but, the conditional statement will be further down the page, than where the button needs to be in the markup.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container TransactionTableResult" style="padding-top:3px">
    @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
      <button type="button" id="MoveToggle" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="button" title="Click to toggle display of move transactions.">Moves</button>
    }
  @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
  {        
   <table id="LogTable" class="table table-striped  table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        @foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Model[0]))
        {
            <th>@descriptor.Name</th>
        }
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach (Dashboard.Areas.Transact_Part.BusinessLayer.Models.Transaction trans in Model)
       {
           string hide =  trans.TRANS.Equals("M") ? "display:none" : "";
           <tr  style="white-space:nowrap; @hide">
              @foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(trans))
              {
                  <td>
                    @descriptor.GetValue(trans)
                  </td>
              }
           </tr>
       }
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, you want to show/hide the button based on a condition that depends on the table value? If so, why not just keeping the button inside the `if` that you already have and change the condition to make it depend on the table value?

Comment: True, I can move it inside the other condition since they're identical (I missed that as I added the button later). The condition is checked while iterating through the list and creating the table elements. Because I am iterating here, and need to, to have the table at this point, this is when the condition will be checked (if trans.equals("M") is always false then hide button). So the condition will not be determined until it reaches the second foreach. so I figured instead of iterating twice, and other than adding javascript, if there was a way to modify the code higher  up using Razor.

Comment: You can declare a variable at the beginning, let's say `var showButton = true;` then use it to show/hide the button and inside your iteration change the value according to your needs.

Comment: But it will already have passed this line: "<button type="button" id="MoveToggle" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="button" title="Click to toggle display of move transactions.">Moves</button>" before the variable is set... Sorry if I am confusing, but I am not sure how to correctly relay what I am asking other than how I am already asking.

Comment: Do not confuse what I am asking with, "string hide =  trans.TRANS.Equals("M") ? "display:none" : "";" that line, as that is to default the row that contains M to hidden, but I am asking how to hide the button to toggle showing this row on and off, when there are no rows that contain "M": "<button type="button" id="MoveToggle" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="button" title="Click to toggle display of move transactions.">Moves</button>"

Comment: Yeah now I understand, but there is no way to do this I'm afraid

Comment: @tocqueville, yea to my knowledge I didn't think so either :/ But there should be daRn it! :)

Comment: The simple answer is no, you cannot. You *can* conditionally render a section, but as you've observed, not from a partial. Partials are rendered in a different context than the main view, and cannot affect the layout, as a result.